# javascript - how to implement `not` in querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selectors-api

Quick question:
let's say you have 2 different types of `<button>`,
 
First one looks something like this:  `<button class="test">`
 
Second looks like this:  `<button class="test" disabled="disabled">`.

Now, how can one achieve a selection of the disabled button without selecting the `activated` button? Cause if you go by class, `querySelector` would get both of them. Is there a way to implement some kind of logic into the selection made by `querySelector`?

Something like this maybe -> `"select button with class 'test' AND NOT attribute 'disabled'"`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same way you do it in any other selector. With [the negation pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation).

```
:not([disabled])
```